# Using Mysql with MyISAM as db engine with quartz scheduler

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler, myisam

I have legacy application which is using Mysql 5.6 database with database engine as MyISAM. Now I need to write quartz scheduler which is going to trigger multiple quartz jobs. For that I am using quartz 2.3.2. To use quartz I need to create quartz tables in my schema, I got the tables creation script  from github of quartz repo from [Here](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_mysql.sql).

While I tries to create tables using MyISAM DB engine its failing because length of primary key is more than 1000 bytes.  Error below-

```
Query: CREATE TABLE QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    JOB_CLASS_NAME   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    IS_DURABLE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    IS_NONCONCURRENT VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    IS_UPDATE_DATA VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
)ENGINE=MYISAM;

Error Code: 1071
Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

I am using utf8 as character encoding.

If I try it with InnoDB it works fine.

The question is all other tables in this legacy application is using MyISAM as db engine. So can I use InnoDB for only quartz related tables? Because I am not sure about will there be any performance issues later, as I am using different engines for different tables. 
Can some body please help me out with this issue.

Comment: You can use innodb for any and all tables. Check your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in your settings as it defaults to really small and extensive use will necessate a rise. Alternately do all of SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP need to be utf8, and of their prescribed lengths, because its odd that its distirbuted in a way that doesn't install.

Comment: They even suggest to use InnoDB in the comment: "PLEASE consider using mysql with innodb tables to avoid locking issues"

Comment: @danblack, I tried changing character encoding to latin1, it works, but not sure weather that will cause any issue in the functionality of quartz. testing it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below error with MyISAM database engine is reported as bug in MySql:

```
Error Code: 1071
Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

Reported [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4541)

Mysql developers says that it is not a bug, but its limitation, it has other alternatives,  hence it is takes lower priority.

Due to UTF-8 its taking 3 byte per character

latin1 = 1 byte = 1 chararcter

uft8  = 3 byte = 1 chararcter

Now I am using latin1 as character encoding only for quartz tables, As seed scripts given in quartz repo will not run.

Answer (score 0):

- Full UTF-8 needs utf8mb4, which takes up to 4 bytes per character.
- Switch to InnoDB; performance will be better.  Perhaps even if you have a mixture of tables (some MyISAM, some InnoDB)
- Switch to InnoDB; you won't have to `REPAIR` tables after power failures.
- Switch to InnoDB before MyISAM is removed.
- If your `JOB_NAMEs` (etc) are not really 200 characters, shorten the declaration.
- If your `JOB_NAMEs` (etc) only use ascii, then switch the `CHARACTER SET`.  (It is OK to mix charsets; however, it may cause some issues on `JOINs`.
- Normalize `SCHED_NAME`; it is wasting a lot of space in a lot of tables.